# How Do I create in memory search indexes in Elixir

Tags: search, indexing, elixir, ecto, in-memory

I am currently working on an Elixir/Phoenix project and I was wondering what is a good way to create a quick in-memory search index.

The index would be created on request and destroyed when the request is over and currently the data comes from a database via Ecto.  Also, I would like to query it by different indexes so not just by `:id` but other indexes Example `:user_id` so a flat key value store may not be enough.

Are there any tools that would be helpful?  I looked a bit into mnesia but when using it with `ecto3_mnesia`, a local file/folder was created and I would prefer if everything was in memory.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... if you are only needing to store information for the duration of the request, then the easiest place to do that is inside the `conn` struct -- it is passed to every plug and controller.  Solutions like `:mnesia` or `cachex` would only be useful if you wanted to persist data beyond a single request.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about `ecto3_mnesia`, but I am pretty sure raw `:mnesia` without any redundant wrapper is a good fit here (or, even, [`:ets`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html) if you don’t need a clustered solution.)

[`:mnesia.table_create/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#create_table-2) accepts many options, two you might be interested in are `disc_copies` and `raw_copies`. Simply initialize the former with empty node list and the latter with your complete node list, and you are all set: no disk copies are created, everything is in memory.